# Nginx Rewrite problems (ninja-media-script)

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, nginx, url-rewriting

i buyed this script: http://codecanyon.net/item/ninja-media-script/6822888

But i would like to run this on a nginx Server.

Now i got the Problem that i must convert the htaccess to nginx rewrite.
After hours of trying i hope you can help me.

First .htaccess is this in root folder:

    `RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule ^$ public/ [L]
    RewriteRule (.*) public/$1 [L]`

in root/public i got this htaccess.

`Options -MultiViews
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]`

Can someone help me please? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First one would be

```
rewrite ^ /public last;
```

But I believe you could replace that by changing the root of the virtual server.

The second one

```
try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$request_uri;
```

If you need further help with where or how you should place this in your config please tell me.

Comment: Thanks :) changing the root was helpful.